# Blob Storage Event in databricks through Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

I want to take collect the blob creation events to Event Hub and extract the event details in Databricks.

1. I have successfully able to create a event subscription to route the blob creation event to Event Hub.
2. I have created a Databrick Notebook where I have been able to read stream in Event Hub with below code

```py
conf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)

read_df = (
  spark
    .readStream
    .format("eventhubs")
    .options(**conf)
    .load()
)
```

Now my query is how can I get the blob creation details (for example: get the file details, location, name, size) in the Event in databricks, so that I can process the file created.

Comment: have you tried to create any blob after you started this stream? By default, EventHubs reads only new events, if you want to read old events, you need to adjust configuration...

Comment: If you use `Event Grid schema`, you can get which request you did in the body. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#event-grid-schema

Comment: Yes I have created the blob and got the event details in readstream dataframe as well. My query is how can I extract these details from readstream dataframe.